# Zlib gunzip only returning partial file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gzip, zlib

I have a 27MB .gz file (127MB unzipped). Using ruby's Zlib to ungzip the file returns correctly formatted data, but the file is truncated to a fraction of the expected size (1290 rows of data out of 253,000).

```
string_io = StringIO.new(body)
file = File.new("test.json.gz", "w+")
file.puts string_io.read
file.close

# string_io.read.length == 26_675_650
# File.size("test.json.gz") == 27_738_775
```

Using GzipReader:

```
data = ""
File.open(file.path) do |f|
  gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(f)
  data << gz.read
  gz.close
end
# data.length = 603_537
```

Using a different GzipReader method:

```
data = ""
Zlib::GzipReader.open(file.path) do |gz|
  data << gz.read
end
# data.length == 603_537
```

Using gunzip:

```
gz = Zlib.gunzip(string_io.read)
# gz.length == 603_537
```

The expected size is 127,604,690 but I'm only able to extract 603,537. Using gunzip in my terminal correctly extracts the entire file but I'm looking for a programmatic way to handle this.

Comment: where are you defining `body` ?

Comment: @lacostenycoder `body` is a string that I'm pulling from an S3 bucket

Answer (score 2):

Instead of opening a file and passing a file handler, have you tried using `Zlib::GzipReader.open()`? It's documented here https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/GzipReader.html

I tested locally and was able to get proper results:

```
data = ''
=> ""

Zlib::GzipReader.open('file.tar.gz') { |gz|
  data << gz.read
}

data.length
=> 750003
```

Then checked the file size uncompressed:

```
gzip -l file.tar.gz                                                                                                                           
  compressed uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
      315581       754176  58.1% file.tar
```

Edit: Saw your update that you are pulling the data via S3 API. Make sure you are Base64 decoding your body before writing it to a file.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have tried this and got the same result:

`file = File.open("test.json.gz", "w+");
file.puts string_io;
file.close;
# File.size("test.json.gz") == 27738775;

data = "";
Zlib::GzipReader.open(file.path) do |gz|;
    data << gz.read;
end;
# data.length == 603537;`

Comment: You are most likely writing your file incorrectly. Write the file, exit to shell and attempt using the gunzip tool to extract and be sure it works. You should probably use Zlib::GzipWriter to write the file: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/GzipWriter.html - Also see my update about decoding base64 that is possibly returned from S3 api

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility for why you might be having problems here...

Some GZip data stored by AWS in S3 is in a format that is designed to be streamed a little at a time. As such there are actually multiple GZip chunks concatenated together into a single file. This confuses Zip::GzipReader, which expects to be able to read a single GZip file from start to finish with one header and one footer ([The issue is described here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9790)).

Thankfully they've added a relatively easy workaround.

**Instead of this:**

```rb
data = ""
File.open(file.path) do |f|
  gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(f)
  data << gz.read
  gz.close
end
```

**Do this:**

```rb
data = File.open('tmpfile.gz') { |f| Zlib::GzipReader.zcat(f) }
```